# Why do I get UserRecoverableAuthException: AppDownloadRequired when making an authenticated Google Cloud Endpoints call from Android?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an Android app that uses Google+ Sign in and makes calls to a service running on Google App Engine using Google Cloud Endpoints. The calls are authenticated - the user is picking a Google account before making any of them, then we use the generated client library for our service API within an AsyncTask to make the call to the server.

We're passing the GoogleAccountCredential instance to the builder for the Endpoints service and in other activities in the app, I can make endpoints calls just fine. I can see no difference between this problem activity and the others. The exception is repeatable. Here's the stack trace:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:284)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.eliotstock.bike.task.ProvisionDeviceTask.doInBackground(ProvisionDeviceTask.java:55)
at com.eliotstock.bike.task.ProvisionDeviceTask.doInBackground(ProvisionDeviceTask.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: AppDownloadRequired
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
... 12 more
```

And here's the activity code for building the service:

```
Biketracker.Builder builder = new Biketracker.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), googleAccountCredential);        
this.endpointsService = builder.build();
```

and for executing the Endpoints method:

```
Biketracker.User.ProvisionDevice provisionDevice = endpointsService.user().provisionDevice(deviceId);
provisionDevice.execute();
```

I don't even know what's meant by "AppDownloadRequired". Which app? When debugging this, I've looked for an Intent on the exception that I might fire off, but it's null. Searching elsewhere has shown up very little. Mystified.